# Converting multiple text sequence files into Fasta files in R

Tags: r, file, file-writing, fasta, dna-sequence

I have 100s of DNA sequence files that are text files, and i want to convert them in Fasta format. I have tried with `cat`  but its not giving expected output.
How can I convert these files into fasta format in  R?

example :

```
file1.txt

ATCTACGTACGTGCATG


file2.txt

CGTAGCATTGCATGATC
```

Expected output

```
file1.fa

>file1
ATCTACGTACGTGCATG


file2.fa

>file2
CGTAGCATTGCATGATC
```

Comment: This appears to be a package recommendation request. Surely it should have been available as a Google search. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do using the for loop, but I didn't find a package or more simplest way.

This approach is working.

```
  files1<-list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
  for (i in 1:length(files1))
  {
  logFile = read.table(paste0(files1[i]))
  
  write.table(rbind(paste0(">",files1[i]),logFile),paste0(files1[i],".fa"),row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE)
  
  }
```