# convert multiple SEQ files to fasta format

Tags: r, sequence, fasta

Is there a way to convert hundreds of SEQ files to FASTA format

the seq files contain only the sequence in text format.

```
ATGCGATCGGACTGACTAGCTACGTACG
ACATCCATCATTATTCTATCTATCTATC
ACTATTCATCTATCTTACTATCTTACTC
AATCATTTCATTA
```

How can I append the file name of each individual text file as the string ID?

I tried applying code from [this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940828/converting-multiple-text-sequence-files-into-fasta-files-in-r) like this:

```
files1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.seq")   
files1 
head(files1) 
for (i in 1:length(files1)) {   
  logFile = read.table(paste0(files1[i]))      
  write.table(rbind(paste0(">",files1[i]),logFile),paste0(files1[i],".fa"),row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE) 
}
```

but it did not work, the output would just be a +

Comment: In what way did it not work? Can you provide the code you tried and any output or error messages?

Comment: `files1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.seq") 
 files1
head(files1)
for (i in 1:length(files1))
{
  logFile = read.table(paste0(files1[i]))
  
  write.table(rbind(paste0(">",files1[i]),logFile),paste0(files1[i],".fa"),row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE)
}`and the output would just be a `+`

Comment: the `+` is just saying there is something more, sought by the compiler, to signify having gotten to the end of the entry, typically a `)` or `}`, that is desired and 'waited for' in an interactive environment, wherein after, either execution or error happens. So, put your comment lines above as what you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this for a `.seq` file, which is generated by lasergene DNA (or DNAStar I think).

The format of the `.seq` is:

```
"Contig 2" (1,1412)
  Contig Length:                 1412 bases
  Average Length/Sequence:        757 bases
  Total Sequence Length:         4544 bases
  Top Strand:                       4 sequences
  Bottom Strand:                    2 sequences
  Total:                            6 sequences
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     contig          1..1412
                     /Note="Contig 2(1>1412)"
                     /dnas_scaffold_ID=0
                     /dnas_scaffold_POS=0
     coverage_below  1..568
                     /Note="Below threshold"
     coverage_one    569..749
                     /Note="One_strand"
     coverage_below  750..1331
                     /Note="Below threshold"
     coverage_one    1332..1412
                     /Note="One_strand"

^^
ATGC
```

The sequence data always proceeded `^^`. So I wrote this simple function to read in the .seq file (plan text), and write out fasta file with the file name as the header.

```
convert_seq_to_fasta = function(path){
  
  # read in file
  lines = readLines(path)
  # find where ^^ is - fasta data is the next line
  start = which(lines %in% "^^") + 1
  
  # get name and create output name
  file_name = gsub(".seq", "", path)
  output = paste0(file_name, ".fasta")
  
  # create fasta header and store fasta body
  fasta_header = paste0(">", file_name)
  fasta_body = lines[start]
  
  # write out
  cat(fasta_header, file = output, sep = "\n")
  cat(fasta_body, file = output, append = TRUE)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
seq_files = list.files(pattern = "*.seq$")

for (files in seq_files) {
  convert_seq_to_fasta(files)
}
```

This assumes the `.seq` files are in the same directory as the script (so save it first).

If your `.seq` files have this format, assuming the file name is `rando.seq`:

```
ATGCGATCGGACTGACTAGCTACGTACG
ACATCCATCATTATTCTATCTATCTATC
ACTATTCATCTATCTTACTATCTTACTC
AATCATTTCATTA
```

And you want this output:

```
>rando
ATGCGATCGGACTGACTAGCTACGTACGACATCCATCATTATTCTATCTATCTATCACTATTCATCTATCTTACTATCTTACTCAATCATTTCATT
```

Which is header + sequence data on one line then you can use this function:

```
convert_odd_to_fasta = function(path){
  lines = readLines(path)
  file_name = gsub(".seq", "", path)
  output = paste0(file_name, ".fasta")
  fasta_header = paste0(">", file_name)
  fasta_body = paste0(lines, collapse = '')
  cat(fasta_header, file = output, sep = "\n")
  cat(fasta_body, file = output, append = TRUE)
  
}
```

Use it the same as above.

Hope that helps!